# How to sanitise image field content to make sure it doesn't contain html form in django?

Tags: django, image, python-imaging-library, html-sanitizing

I have included imagefield in my django app and in the documentation I read that the validation done by the ImageField is not sufficient. I wanted to validate the image content to make user doesn't submit any html form.

Is there any way to make sure that the image content is valid that it is not any sort of html under image extension.

Answer (score 0):

In Django 2.2, it seems that the [ImageField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#imagefield) form field does check that the image is valid (which relies on the pillow library) I am not sure why you would want to add any extra validation on top of that.